# Get the result of inserted Entity in Database First approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I mapped the **Insert/Update/Delete** to **StoredProcedure** and tried to insert some entity to database but it seems that the ***DbContext*** doesn't update the ID of the inserted Entity so i can get the latest or just inserted data to database.

This is my StoredProcedure mapped to DbSet.Insert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tblEM_Currencies_INSERT] 
@CurrencyID INT,
@Type NVARCHAR(50),
@Description NVARCHAR(MAX),
@Forex Decimal
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO 
        tblEM_Currencies (Type, Description, Forex)
    VALUES 
        (@Type, @Description, @Forex)

     SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS CurrencyID  
END
```

and this is my Insert in DAL

```
public tblEM_Currencies Insert(tblEM_Currencies entity)
    {
        context.tblEM_Currencies.Add(entity);

        return entity;
    }
```

any help would be appreciated.. TIA

Comment: When you mapped your Insert to the Stored Procedure did you make sure to add a Result Column Binding to the primary key?